# TP-Link AC600 Archer T2E PCIe card is not recognized by Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, pcie

I recently purchased a new TP-Link AC600 Archer T2E Wireless Dual Band PCIe Adapter for a new build. I have tested this card in 2 machines running Ubuntu 20.04, but I've gotten the same result. I couldn't even get the light on the bracket of the card to signal, leading me to think it was defective. To be sure, I put the card in yet a different machine running Windows 10, and it worked without hesitation.

`lspci` appears to recognize the card as "Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b821" which is incorrect. I am currently on kernel 5.15.0-60-generic.

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10de] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection [1028:027f]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801JD/DO (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:3a67] (rev 02)
--
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b821]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b821]
```

[image: Command lspci]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. AS TEXT PLEASE, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Please post the full output.

Comment: Posted edit. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install drivers for it. Connect to the internet by other means and run

```
sudo apt install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
```

You'll have to `make` and `sudo make install` after each kernel upgrade.

But the 22.04 Ubuntu release with a HWE 5.19 kernel will support the device initially.

Comment: This set of drivers didn't work. After attempting this solution I did some additional digging with other drivers, but have had no success. I will put 22.04 on my new build and see it if works that way. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This driver should work. Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: I did not disable Secure Boot. I installed 22.04 on my new build instead and the device worked correctly (as you stated it would). The only reason I had instated 20.04 LTS initially was because I had a boot drive made and available to me.